# getting Clean Sources Plus

Tags: c#

written by Jeff Atwood, this program cleans the project folders from bin, obj and Resharper files ... BUT its downlaod link is broken , does anybody know where can I get it from ?

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/clean-sources-plus.html

Comment: https://github.com/coding-horror/CleanSourcesPlus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download from this [link](http://www.raghurana.com/clean-sources-plus)

Answer (score 3):

Update: This comment was left by [Christian Junk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100863/christian-junk)

> https://github.com/coding-horror/CleanSourcesPlus

Which seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

---

Old answer:

I can't find Clean Source Plus, but I did find [Tree Trim](http://code.google.com/p/treetrim/), which seems to do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

TreeTrim is very cool but it will report an exception when i try to clean svn work copy. the exception message just like " no privilege to delete all-wcprops...".
i got the source code and fixed the issue, so if someone like TreeTrim, you can download the setup file on http://db.tt/hFdwQWId

Hi, Everyone,  i just found a good alternative---CleanPoject from http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Thank%20you%20for%20installing%20CleanProject, Maybe we can replace CleanSourcePlus with CleanProject.